# How can I use crosshair in GFlot

Tags: java, charts, flot

I know that flot has a crosshair plugin - but I can't see how to use it from Java in GFlot.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the examples on this site:
http://1.gflot2.appspot.com/#tracking